# Count first occurring record per time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table `trips` , I have two columns: `created_at` and `user_id`

Unique users take many different trips. My goal is to count the  *very first*  trip made unique per each `user_id`s per year-month.  I understand that in this case the `min()` function should be applied.

In a previous query, all unique users per year-month were aggregated:

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM trips
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Where in the above query should `min()` be integrated? In other words, instead of counting all unique user id's per month, I only need to count the first occurrence of unique user id per month.

The sample input would look like:

```
> routes
   user_id          created_at
1        1 2015-08-07 07:18:21
2        2 2015-05-06 20:43:52
3        3 2015-05-06 20:53:54
4        1 2015-03-30 20:09:07
5        2 2015-10-01 18:28:32
6        3 2015-08-07 07:29:29
7        1 2015-08-28 13:45:44
8        2 2015-08-07 07:37:31
9        3 2015-03-30 20:14:04
10       1 2015-08-07 07:08:50
```

And the output would be:

```
   count     Y-m   
1        0 2015-01 
2        0 2015-02 
3        2 2015-03
4        0 2015-04 
5        1 2015-05
```

Because the first occurrences of `user_id` 1 and 3 were in March and the first occurrence of `user_id` 2 was in May

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: sure I've included some sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with 2 levels of aggregation. Get the `min` time per user_id and then `count`.

```
SELECT to_char(first_time, 'YYYY-MM'),count(*)
from (
SELECT user_id,MIN(created_at) as first_time
FROM trips
GROUP BY user_id
) t
GROUP BY to_char(first_time, 'YYYY-MM')
```